Bootstrap modal causes page to scroll to iframe
I have a page with an iFrame to another site that uses Bootstrap (v5.1). The bootstrap page uses a modal both when it loads and when a certain button is clicked. When the modal shows up, the outer page automatically scrolls to the iFrame and skips all the content at the top. This would be fine for the button click, but not ideal when the screen loads. Is there a way to disable this automatically scrolling to a modal in Bootstrap?
iFrame on main page
<div id="header">
    <!-- lots of content here -->
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <!-- lots of content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="my-container">
        <iframe src="https://contoso.com" id="myIframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

Modal on Bootstrap Page
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="PopupTitle">Test Popup</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
                    <div class="control-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" name="myID" id="myID" placeholder="Enter ID" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description" />
                    </div
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div><button type="button" id="searchButton" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


I figured this out, there is some logic in Bootstrap that focuses on the Modal. You can disable this scrolling behavior by removing the "fade" class, or by commenting out the focus trap line as shown below in bootstrap.js. Make sure it is the one under the modal section.
const transitionComplete = () => {
  if (this._config.focus) {
    this._focustrap.activate();    //Removed this line
  }

  this._isTransitioning = false;
  EventHandler.trigger(this._element, EVENT_SHOWN$3, {
      relatedTarget
  });
};

